# Sanitizing HTML Input with Trix

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, trix

I have a strange issue at the moment, and I'm looking for any insight on how to deal with this.

I'm currently accepting HTML input using the [Basecamp Trix editor](https://github.com/basecamp/trix).

When I send the input to my Laravel application, it is saved to my database as:

```
<div>&lt;script&gt;alert('test');&lt;/script&gt;</div>
```

However, the problem is that when I insert this into a Vue property using Laravel's blade, it somehow actually converts it back into valid HTML:

```
<reply :data-reply="{{ $reply }}"></reply>
```

Result:

[image]

It seems that Laravel converts the script tags to valid HTML using the blade echo statements?

My View:

```
{{ $reply }}
```

Result:

```
{"id":63,"created_at":"2017-09-07 13:30:53","updated_at":"2017-09-07 13:35:05","user_id":1,"body":"<div><script>alert('test');<\/script><\/div>","options":null}
```

The problem is, I can't sanitize this because the HTML data is actually escaped in my database, but when Laravel converts my reply to JSON, it actually unescapes the script tags, and it's actually ran in Vue when using the `v-html` directive.

I know I'm not supposed to accept user input while using the `v-html` directive, but I need HTML support for replies, and I can't sanitize already escaped HTML in my Laravel application.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can go about sanitizing Trix's content in some way?

Comment: try `<reply :data-reply="{!! $reply !!}"></reply>` ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've put

```
<div>&lt;script&gt;alert('test');&lt;/script&gt;</div>
```

into email field of user.

In Laravel I'm just using:

```
return view('welcome', ['user' => App\User::find(1)]);
```

nothing special in model.

My view looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div id="el">{{ $user }}</div>
<script>
    user = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("el").innerHTML);
    console.log(user.name);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and in JS console I'm getting:

```
&lt;div&gt;&lt;script&gt;alert('test');&lt;/script&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
```

so it's not the same as in database but it doesn't look as you showed either.

Comment: This won't actually work since I'm passing the entire `Reply` object that is `json_encoded` by Laravel when passed through the regular escape brackets. Also, the tags `{!! !!}` will not unescape anything, it's actually the opposite. Thanks though!

Comment: @SteveBauman Sorry, I've misread your question, I've updated my answer

Comment: Still does the same thing actually, for some reason, when the reply model is passed to Vue using the `{{ }}` laravel tags, it converts the script tags in the replies body to valid HTML: `<div><script>alert('test');</script></div>`

Comment: @SteveBauman Look at my edit, are you sure you are getting valid HTML again? I'm getting exact opposite. Make sure it's not the Vue that is converting it back again into HTML

Comment: Hmmmm... What is rendered in the actual view for your user model? Do you see if the tags are converted back into actual HTML tags? I'm using Laravel 5.5 by the way, are your on 5.5?

Comment: @SteveBauman Yes, this is 5.5 as you see everything was escaped. Have you tried to use exact same code as I showed on your machine and verify the result?

Comment: I'll try! Also, it seems that I just resolved it by using `htmlentities` on the reply body that is received by the server, for example: `$reply->body = htmlentities($request->body);` I'll post back with my results with your suggestion as well

Comment: I get this: `{"id":4,"created_at":"2017-09-05 09:58:23","updated_at":"2017-09-07 14:53:51","deleted_at":null,"name":"<div><script>alert('test');<\/script><\/div>","email":"email@test.ca"}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153905/discussion-between-marcin-nabialek-and-steve-bauman).